# Hashtable "Unresolved compilation" in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-7

this is my class

```
package main;

import java.util.Hashtable;

public class Information {

    private final static String name = "Info Name";
    private final static String direccion = "direction street number";

    Hashtable<String,String> coordenates = new Hashtable<String,String>();
    coordenates.put("lat", "36.564565465");
    coordenates.put("lng", "64.584616511");

}
```

i have learned from [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html)

```
This example creates a hashtable of numbers. It uses the names of the numbers as keys:

   Hashtable<String, Integer> numbers
     = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
   numbers.put("one", 1);
   numbers.put("two", 2);
   numbers.put("three", 3);
To retrieve a number, use the following code:

   Integer n = numbers.get("two");
   if (n != null) {
     System.out.println("two = " + n);
   }
```

what is wrong with my code...

im using Eclipse for Java EE Developers, Java SE SDK 7 (1.7)
on windows 7 64bits

thanks!

Comment: What was the text of the compiler error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to execute code out side of the context of a method, constructor or `static` initialiser...

```
public class Information {

    private final static String name = "Info Name";
    private final static String direccion = "direction street number";

    Hashtable<String,String> coordenates = new Hashtable<String,String>();
    /**
      This belongs in a constructor or method
      coordenates.put("lat", "36.564565465");
      coordenates.put("lng", "64.584616511");
    **/

}
```

Comment: `coordenates` is not `static` so putting `coordenates.put...` inside method, constructor or initialization block (not static one) would be OK. Anyway +1 for fastest answer :)

Comment: Yeah, I "kind of" hinted at that in code comment ;), but given the fact that you can execute code in a method, constructor or static block, I was trying to cover my bases - can't please every body ;)

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to call hashtable.put() outside a method, you can probably do it inside the constructor, I'm not sure what is your requirement, but I guess you can avoid the overhead of hashtable and define two fields lat and long

Answer (score 0):

1.Write it in a main function

```
public static void main(String args[]) {    
    Hashtable<String,String> coordenates = new Hashtable<String,String>();
    coordenates.put("lat", "36.564565465");
     coordenates.put("lng", "64.584616511");    
}
```

2.write it in Constructor

```
    Information() {
      access setter of coordinates to put values
    }
```